# There is something else beside Jackson for complexe objects to handle in Java?

Tags: java, json, spring, validation, jackson

I have to be able, on the backend side, to receive/send a `JSON` structure, like that one below.

```
{  
   "firstObject":{  
      "type":"string",
      "value":"productValue"
   },
   "secondObject":{  
      "type":"string",
      "value":"statusValue"
   },
   "thirdObject":{  
      "type":"map",
      "value":{  
         "customerName":{  
            "type":"string",
            "value":"customerValue"
         }
      }
   },
   "fourthObject":{  
      "type":"map",
      "value":{  
         "firstObject":{  
            "type":"map",
            "value":{  
               "anotherObj1":{  
                  "type":"string",
                  "value":"TEST"
               },
               "anotherObj2":{  
                  "type":"date",
                  "value":"01/12/2018"
               },
               "anotherObj3":{  
                  "type":"date",
                  "value":"31/01/2018"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem that makes this a little bit tricky it's the fact that, for each object, I have to know what kind of type is. There could be 4 types:

- int
- string
- boolean
- map

If the value for an object is `map` (selected by a customer), for example, on the frontend side will appear another key/value structure, so what I'm gonna receive on the backend side is a dynamic structure. I will need to have a validation for this structure, to check if it complies to what I`m expected to receive.

I would appreciate an opinion if I should use just a `Java` class, to make my objects that I need, or to use beside that, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for `JSON` validation and mapping all that objects into a `JSON`.

If I'll use Jackson, I`ll have to make a custom serializer and deserializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Jackson` library you can use `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` annotations. They are handle polymorphic type handling:

- `@JsonTypeInfo` is used to indicate details of what type information is included in serialization
- `@JsonSubTypes` is used to indicate sub-types of annotated type
- `@JsonTypeName` is used to define logical type name to use for annotated class

Your example fits for this solution except root object which looks more like simple `POJO` class. In your case we should craete type structure which help work with these 3 types: `string`, `date`, `map`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StringValue.class, name = "string"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DateValue.class, name = "date"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MapValue.class, name = "map")
})
abstract class HasValue<T> {

    protected T value;

    public HasValue() {
        this(null);
    }

    public HasValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + "{" +
            "value=" + value +
            "}";
    }
}

class StringValue extends HasValue<String> {

    public StringValue() {
        this(null);
    }

    public StringValue(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

class DateValue extends HasValue<String> {

    public DateValue(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public DateValue() {
        this(null);
    }
}

class MapValue extends HasValue<Map<String, HasValue>> {

    public MapValue(Map<String, HasValue> value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public MapValue() {
        this(new LinkedHashMap<>());
    }

    public void put(String key, HasValue hasValue) {
        this.value.put(key, hasValue);
    }
}
```

Now, we need to introduce `POJO` for root value. It could look like below, but you can add getters/setters if you want. For this example below will code be enough:

```
class Root {

    public HasValue firstObject;
    public HasValue secondObject;
    public HasValue thirdObject;
    public HasValue fourthObject;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Root{" +
            "firstObject=" + firstObject +
            ", secondObject=" + secondObject +
            ", thirdObject=" + thirdObject +
            ", fourthObject=" + fourthObject +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Now, we can finally try to serialise and deserialise these objects:

```
MapValue customerName = new MapValue();
customerName.put("customerName", new StringValue("customerValue"));

MapValue innerMap = new MapValue();
innerMap.put("anotherObj1", new StringValue("TEST"));
innerMap.put("anotherObj2", new DateValue("01/12/2018"));
innerMap.put("anotherObj3", new DateValue("31/01/2018"));

MapValue fourthObject = new MapValue();
fourthObject.put("firstObject", innerMap);

Root root = new Root();
root.firstObject = new StringValue("productValue");
root.secondObject = new StringValue("statusValue");
root.thirdObject = customerName;
root.fourthObject = fourthObject;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root);
System.out.println(json);
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Root.class));
```

Aboce code prints `JSON`:

```
{
  "firstObject" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "value" : "productValue"
  },
  "secondObject" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "value" : "statusValue"
  },
  "thirdObject" : {
    "type" : "map",
    "value" : {
      "customerName" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "value" : "customerValue"
      }
    }
  },
  "fourthObject" : {
    "type" : "map",
    "value" : {
      "firstObject" : {
        "type" : "map",
        "value" : {
          "anotherObj1" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "value" : "TEST"
          },
          "anotherObj2" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "value" : "01/12/2018"
          },
          "anotherObj3" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "value" : "31/01/2018"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And `toString` representation:

```
Root{firstObject=StringValue{value=productValue}, secondObject=StringValue{value=statusValue}, thirdObject=MapValue{value={customerName=StringValue{value=customerValue}}}, fourthObject=MapValue{value={firstObject=MapValue{value={anotherObj1=StringValue{value=TEST}, anotherObj2=DateValue{value=01/12/2018}, anotherObj3=DateValue{value=31/01/2018}}}}}}
```

You can easily manipulate output by adding/removing any kind of `HasValue` instance.

For more info see:

1. [Jackson annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)
2. [Jackson Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8)

Answer (score 0):

Download the JSON jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm). From the client side convert your JSON to string using json.stringify (because JSONObject's constructor accepts only string). After receiving the request from the client do this:

```
public void doPost(request,response) throws ParseException, JSONException {
        parseMapFromJSON(request.getParameter("JSONFromClient"));
}
private void parseMapFromJSON(String JSONParam) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject(JSONParam);
    for(int i=0; i<requestJSON.length();i++)
    {
         String key = (String) requestJSON.names().get(i);             
         if(key.endsWith("Object"))
         {
            parseMapFromJSON(requestJSON.get(key).toString());
         }
         else if(key.startsWith("type") && (requestJSON.get(key).equals("date") || requestJSON.get(key).equals("string")))
         {
            System.out.println(requestJSON.get("value"));
            break;
         }
         else if(key.startsWith("type") && requestJSON.get(key).equals("map"))
         {
            parseMapFromJSON(requestJSON.get("value").toString());
         }
         else if(!key.equals("value"))
         {
            parseMapFromJSON(requestJSON.get(key).toString());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

Do you think tho, the manipulation with ASM will be a better suit for this?

[ASM library for manipulation an existing Java class](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asm)

Comment: I don't this so. You don't need any manipulation in your java class. Why would you need that when you are only parsing JSON?